# Sketch: vertical text alignment

Tags: text, sketch-app, alignment

When working with Adobe InDesign it is possible to select how text will be aligned vertically:

[image: Picture of InDesign UI which shows a text-frame and a dialogue for further alignment options of said text-frame]

I am especially interested in having the text vertically centred and was wondering if this is also possible in Sketch.
I figured, that maybe these controls here are responsible for this, however they are greyed out:

[image: Picture of Sketch-UI with highlighted controls, which appear to be greyed out]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sketch only allows to vertically center text if they are `fixed` and do not using the native line-height of the font. This is how you can active the vertical alignment options:

1. Create a text layer
2. Change alignment to `fixed`
3. Grap the handler at the bottom
4. Resize the text box, vertical alignment options will be active

For Example:
When styling a button you can now stretch the fixed text area above the background layer, setting contrains to all directions an voi la, you have a full horizontal and vertical flexible button.